# Create a cytoscape tree from a php code

Tags: php, javascript, xml, yii, cytoscape-web

i'm trying to show the results of a query with a graph using cytoscape. I'm not expert with javascript so maybe it's just a syntax error, can someone take a look on my code?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            // id of Cytoscape Web container div
            var div_id = "cytoscapeweb";

            // NOTE: - the attributes on nodes and edges
            //       - it also has directed edges, which will automatically display edge arrows
            var xml = '\
            <graphml>\
              <key id="label" for="all" attr.name="label" attr.type="string"/>\
              <key id="weight" for="node" attr.name="weight" attr.type="double"/>\
              <graph edgedefault="directed">\
                <node id="1">\
                    <?php echo "<data key=\"label\">$prot</data>\\\n";?>
                    <data key="weight">2.0</data>\
        </node>
    <?php $count=2;?>
    <?php  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<node id=\"$count\">\\";                    
        echo "<data key=\"label\">$row['interactor']</data>\\";
                    echo "<data key=\"weight\">1.0</data>\\";
                echo "</node>\\";
                echo "<edge source="1" target=\"$count\">\\";
                    echo "<data key=\"label\">$prot to $row['interactor']</data>\\";
                echo "</edge>\\";
        $count++;
    }?>
              </graph>\
            </graphml>\
            ';
```

Comment: What behavior are you seeing?  Any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

The XML string written directly in JS uses backslashes to protect the end of lines. Your PHP code also outputs backslashes, but the are not followed by a carriage return. So either you insert `"\n"` after each `"\\"`, either you remove every `"\\"` from your PHP code.

An advice: when things go wrong, also look at the HTML source code of the page in your browser. This error should be obvious there. And learn to use the JS consoles of the web browsers (e.g. inside Chrome and Opera, Ctrl-Shift-i opens a developer toolbar with an error panel).